# Rasterio rasterize function : unable to insert correct geometries

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, fiona

Trying to rasterize a polylines shapefile with a specific attribute using rasterize function from Rasterio library. This function needs an iterable containing tuples of (geometry, value), with the geometry being a GeoJSON-like object (see [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.rasterize)). This geometry can be extracted with fiona or geopandas, I've read [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151339/rasterize-a-shapefile-with-geopandas-or-fiona-python) and tried it (so with geopandas) but the geometry is not correct, as I tested it with the "is_valid_geom" and the result is "false" which seems logical because when I print this geometry it displays: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001903856C048>`. I also tried with Fiona like this :

```
shapeee = fiona.open(shapefile) 
geom_fiona = [shapes['geometry'] for shapes in shapeee]
attrib_fiona = [shapes['properties']['OBJECTID'] for shapes in shapeee] # attribute
print(features.is_valid_geom(geom_fiona)) # FALSE
```

which also returns "false" but I don't understand why because the geometry seems to be correct :

```
print(geom_fiona)
"[{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(177421.98120000213, 142766.21020000055), (177409.1555000022, 142781.71609999985), (177392.76659999788, 142801.65300000086) and so on..."
```

So at the end when I try to rasterize I don't get any error message but the output is a blank image with all values to 0... The rasterization code :

```
tuples = []
for i in range(0,len(geom_fiona)-1,1):
    tuples.append([geom_fiona[i],attrib_fiona[i]])
burned = features.rasterize(tuples, out_shape=new_dataset.shape,default_value=-99,dtype=rasterio.float64)
```

Note : I already read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269947/rasterio-does-not-execute-the-rasterize-function) and the projections are the same between my shapefile and the raster that is used to raterized

Anyone has an idea of what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry was actually valid! `features.is_valid_geom(geom_fiona)` returned `false` because I put the entire geometry as argument. Writing `features.is_valid_geom(geom_fiona[0])` returned `True`. But the rasterization is still incorrect and nothing changed...